# IAR ambiguous section match failed error(Lc037)

Tags: linker, arm, iar

I would like to create several Flash region in ICF file, but I encountered some trouble.
Please refer to below link: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/bTjeqs7Ymy

I am trying to split flash to different block: Bootcode / Parameter / User code / Discharge areas and I get errors as:

```
Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro data section .rodata in usbiap_vars.o" matches more than one pattern

"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro data section .data_init in system_mb9abxxx.o" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in abort.o(dl7M_tln.a)" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in abort.o(dl7M_tln.a)" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in startup_mb9xfxxx.o" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in fpinit_M.o(m7M_tlv.a)" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in cmain.o(rt7M_tl.a)" matches more than one pattern 
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

Error[Lc037]: ambiguous section match: "ro code section .text in cexit.o(rt7M_tl.a)" matches more than one pattern          
"ro" (at line 71 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf")  
"ro" (at line 73 of "D:\Data\Fujitsu\Workspace\porting\bootcode2\config\mb9bf568.icf") 

.... many Errors.
```

`The line 71 :place in BOOTCODE_region   { readonly,
                              block FIXED_ORDER_ROM };`
`The line 73 :place in PARAMS_region   { readonly };`

I am new on this, I would be appreciated if any suggestion!
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (which may not be totally correct - (I'm new too, but this is what fixed my issue):

The line 71 :place in BOOTCODE_region { block FIXED_ORDER_ROM };

The line 73 :place in PARAMS_region { readonly };

In my instance it didn't like readonly being in multiple regions.  This means you would want your readonly code in PARAMS_region and your other region that has the block be limited to that block.  I don't know if there's another workaround.